# Edge Server Includes (ESI)

Tags: http, caching, cdn, edge-side-includes

Is it a good practice to use ESI's or is that an older technology? are there alternatives that would be better. I am familiar with the use of CDN's and cache servers but this ESI was typically for applications that do more than just load the front end.

Comment: Curious why you ask - are you planning to use ESI for something outside the CDN context?

Answer (score 3):

ESI is fairly unknown outside the CDN context. However, I think there are a number of interesting use cases for its use 'closer' to the origin servers now that we see a lot more interest in splitting the applications that deliver Web sites into several self-contained services. An ESI-enabled cache is a good means to integrate these services into a single Web site.